# MailKit.Security.AuthenticationException: 'LOGIN failed.' - IMAP /SMTP/POP Client

Tags: c#, authentication, smtp, office365, imap

**I'm trying to read an email from my mailbox using the MailKit library. Unfortunately the program throws this MailKit.Security.AuthenticationAsync Exception: 'LOGIN failed.'**

- I checked on MailBox server -  Mails are coming .
- I checked Mailbox is Single Factor Authentication.

> "ImapSettings.Server": "outlook.office365.com",
> "ImapSettings.Port": 993,
> "ImapSettings.UserName": "xxxx@domain.com",
> "ImapSettings.Password": "xxxxxxxx"

MailKit.Security.AuthenticationException: 'LOGIN failed.'

`var client = new ImapClient()`

[image]

I also tried with SMTP client but getting same error.

Comment: See [Deprecation of Basic authentication in Exchange Online](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/deprecation-of-basic-authentication-exchange-online)

Comment: What I have to do here. Why Authenticate is not working with UserName and PWD. It was working Last year as per my ScrumMaster.

Comment: Do I have to do Authenticate  with OAuth2?

Comment: How to set up App registration in Portal.Azure.com?

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/healthcare-apis/register-application

Comment: Getting this error : - 

Only loopback redirect uri is supported, but https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient was found. Configure http://localhost or http://localhost:port both during app registration and when you create the PublicClientApplication object. See https://aka.ms/msal-net-os-browser for details. This is Code 
var options = new PublicClientApplicationOptions {
    ClientId = "Application (client) ID",
    TenantId = "Directory (tenant) ID",
    RedirectUri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient"
};

This is Console application.

Comment: Have you tried following to the guide mentioned in the error message?

Comment: After retrieve Token,  Account.UserName is getting NULL
await publicClientApplication.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, authToken.Account).ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken);   -> getting correct Token
But Getting NULL in authToken.Account new SaslMechanismOAuthBearer(authToken.Account.UserName, authToken.AccessToken);